# Passing data from CoreData for editing

Tags: swift, core-data, types, swiftui

I am doing a learner project from HackingWithSwift ([Bookworm](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/bookworm-introduction)). When I try to make an EditBookView to the project outside of the curriculum (ie to get data from CoreData, revise it, then save it) I run into some type related problem. The rating attribute/property is acting up.

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct EditBookView: View {

let book: Book

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

@State private var rating: Int

//the rest of the other attributes

init(book: Book) {

_rating = State(initialValue: Int(book.rating) ?? "") //error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'

//the rest of the other attributes

}
```

I Int it, got that “Can’t convert” error; If I don’t Int it, another error: Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int16' and 'String' . I don’t understand why the system says it’s a string. It specifically make it an Int in the '@State private var .

Many many thanks.

PS

Sorry if the code I post is not enough. I always have difficulties balancing how much or little I should post when I ask a question.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the *original* type of `rating` is in `Book`, but it definitely sounds like an Int of some sort. Right now, you're providing a default *String* value if it is `nil` by specifying `""`. Instead, you should be giving a default *numerical* rating -- 0, for example.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you so much! I replace "" with 3 and now it's just a yellow warning.  But now this error "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" is on my whole init.  But I already var all 6 attributes from the xcdatamodel.  Probably need to research a bit and post another question.  By any chance you have some quick thoughts?

Comment: You need to make sure every property is set -- so, `self.book = book`

Comment: Change `let book: Book` to  `@ObservedObject var book: Book`. You don't need the `@State` just access the variable directly. Unless you truly mean to disconnect the changes from the CoreData object